# Converting SQL stored procedures into Hadoop UDFs

Tags: sql, json, stored-procedures, hadoop, db2

I am new to hadoop and I have been provided with a task to come up with plans and ideas on how to convert the existing DB2 stored procedures into Hadoop UDF. Since Hive doesn't support stored procedures I am stuck.

I did a POC for a simple select statement and it worked:

- POC takes a given SQL file as input and converts it first into an intermediate JSON file
- Reads the JSON file - if any built-in function found, gets the equivalent hive function from a db2-hive functions lookup file.
- Creates a hive SQL file from the intermediate JSON file.
- Currently, it works for a simple SELECT SQL with WHERE clause

But i am unable to replicate it for procedures.
Please suggest me the approach and/or examples to proceed. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific on the issue you encounter and provide a minimum (non)working example.

Comment: @pyStarter At this moment i am looking for more ideas/suggestions on how can I convert a stored procedure in DB2 to hadoop UDF.I just gave the POC example to demonstrate my current approach.Please suggest if it's correct or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Automatically converting the stored procedures is not going to be an easy task.  How many are there?  You most likely will need to manually rewrite them.

Comment: @dan1111 : The number is very high.At this moment we are simply trying to convert a simple stored procedure to Hadoop UDF.Once we successfully do it,we will try to see if there is some way we can automate the conversions.At this moment we are short of ideas on how to convert a DB2 proc to hadoop UDF.Any ideas/suggestions from this community are welcome.

Comment: @user131990, I think your question is mainly about how to approach the general issue of converting an SQL stored procedure to Hadoop.  Thus I have altered the title and tags to hopefully attract more attention.  The DB2 community here is pretty small.

Comment: @dan1111 , At this moment yes,we are open to any ideas/suggestions.